# Java Reg-ex to validate file convention

Tags: java, regex

How to check if the following is part of the file name using regular expressions

```
.en.
.fr.
.pt.
.de.
.ja.
.es.
.it.
.cn.
```

I know one other way is to check the index of and return boolean.

Comment: Well, yes, you could use regular expressions.  Do you have a question about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a match of `\.(en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn|)\.`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the regex...

```
.*\.(?:en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\..*
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression: `\.(?:en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\.` or for `String#matches()`: `.*\.(?:en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\..*` (note that in string literals, you need to escape the `\\`: `".*\\.(?:en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\\..*"`)

Answer (score 1):

```
string.matches(".*\\.(en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\\..*");
```

or you can precompile the pattern with

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.(en|fr|pt|de|ja|es|it|cn)\\..*");
```

and check with `p.matches(string);`